# Valor de boton dentro de tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla generada dinamicamente, dentro de ella tengo un botón al cual deseo obtener su valor

El botón realiza una acción diferente a lo que se asigna su valor por lo que le he asignado ahí un valor para usarlo en otra acción

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera

```
var boton =document.getElementById("tabProd").rows[indice_fila_tabla].cells[6];
alert(boton.value);
```

sin embargo no puedo obtener ese valor

Comment: ¿Como quieres obtener el valor?¿Haciendo clic en el botón? [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/134080/edit) tu pregunta.

Comment: Porfa pon tu código, creo que así sería más fácil poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Si por valor te refieres al texto de un elemento del DOM, una opción es usar [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). Ejemplo:

Se incluye una pequeña tabla con dos filas. La segunda fila cuenta con dos celdas, la segunda celda tiene como texto `5`. Se imprime al log de la consola el texto de la segunda celda de la segunda fila.

```js
var celda = document.getElementById('miTabla').rows[1].cells[1];
console.log(celda.textContent)
```

```html
<table id="miTabla">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>5</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### My JavaScript

```
<html>
        <button class="massshow-modal btn btn-info" 
        data-id="34"
        data-nombre="marcos"
        data-apellido="alberto"

        ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>

        <button class="massshow-modal btn btn-info" 
        data-id="31"
        data-nombre="marcos_3"
        data-apellido="alberto_4"

        ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' class='form-control' id='id_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='nombre_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='apellido_mass' maxlength='45'   required='required' autofocus>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  // Show a post
        $(document).on('click', '.massshow-modal', function() {
            //$('.modal-descripcion').text('Vista de los Datos');
            //$('#msdelete').text(' ');
            $('#id_mass').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#nombre_mass').val($(this).data('nombre'));
            $('#apellido_mass').val($(this).data('apellido'));

            //$('#massModal').modal('show');
            //$('#acciones').attr('class', 'btn btn-info hibe');
            //$('#acciones').text('Visible');
            //$('#acciones').attr('disabled');

        });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```